# Vanishing mean flux

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, phase-space

Given a phase-space distribution function in special relativity, we can define the following Lorentz invariant vector -

$$S^a(x^i) = c\int \frac{d^3p}{E_{p}}P^a f(x^i, p).$$

The spatial component of this vector describes the mean flux of particles along the direction of $P^a$. The symbols have the usual meaning (Momentum 4-vector, and Energy).

Now, I have read that it is always possible to choose a Lorentz frame, where the mean flux vanishes locally around an event P.

My question is, how can this be done? Is the frame a co-moving frame with particles, since we are making mean velocity vanish, can there even be a co-moving frame for this?.
Further, I have read, if the gradient of mean velocity is sufficiently small, such a frame can be defined globally. Can someone explain why a global frame can't be described without this condition?

I feel I am missing something very basic but I can't seem to figure it out.